# Unable to drop items in the cart

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate shopping cart automation on the below link : http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/droppable.php

I am able to locate the elements under product but the products are not moving to cart, I tried all the options as below but it is not  at all adding to cart:

```
Actions drag = new Actions(chromeDriver);

        WebElement tShirt = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-1\"]"));
        WebElement bags = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-3\"]"));
        WebElement gadgets = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-5\"]"));
        WebElement cart = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cart\"]/div"));

if(tShirt.isEnabled())
        {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            System.out.println(chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-2\"]/ul/li[1]")).getText());
            System.out.println(cart.getText()); 
            drag.dragAndDrop(chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-2\"]/ul/li[1]")),cart).build().perform();
            drag.dragAndDropBy(chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-2\"]/ul/li[1]")),(cart.getLocation().getX()),(cart.getLocation().getY())).build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            drag.clickAndHold(chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-2\"]/ul/li[2]"))).moveToElement(cart).release().build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            drag.clickAndHold(chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ui-id-2\"]/ul/li[2]"))).release(cart).build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(4000);

        }
```

But unable to drop multiple elements in the cart. Is there anything I am missing here?

P.S. : I've already switched to frame present on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply below code;

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);                    
act.dragAndDrop(tShirt, cart).build().perform();
act.dragAndDrop(bags, cart).build().perform();
act.dragAndDrop(gadgets, cart).build().perform();
```

Comment: under t shirt there are sub elements as well which has to be added in the cart hence the above solution is not working.